# opensuse syslinux in a submenu

Tags: pxe-boot, opensuse, syslinux

I'm trying to create a netboot installer that allows installing various versions of linux.  My TFTP server is dnsmasq from debian wheezy.  I've got debian, ubuntu, and fedora working fine, but I'm having trouble with opensuse.  Here's a snippet of my pxelinux config (using pxelinux 4.05 from ubuntu 12.04):

```
label openSUSE-11.4-i386
menu label openSUSE 11.4 i386
menu indent 2
config openSUSE-11.4-i386/isolinux.cfg openSUSE-11.4-i386/
label openSUSE-11.4-x86_64
menu label openSUSE 11.4 x86_64
menu indent 2
config openSUSE-11.4-x86_64/isolinux.cfg openSUSE-11.4-x86_64/
label openSUSE-12.1-i386
menu label openSUSE 12.1 i386
menu indent 2
config openSUSE-12.1-i386/isolinux.cfg openSUSE-12.1-i386/
```

Here's a snippet of the openSUSE isolinux.cfg:

```
label linux
  kernel linux
  append initrd=initrd splash=silent showopts
```

Fedora (which works fine) looks like:

```
label linux
  menu label ^Install or upgrade Fedora
  menu default
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img quiet
```

Two weird things are happening.

1. When I select `openSUSE 12.1 i386`, my tftp server shows an error like `cannot access /var/ftpd/openSUSE-12.1-i386/../::openSUSE-12.1-x86_64/isolinux.cfg: Permission denied`.

   - Where it's getting `openSUSE-12.1-x86_64` is beyond me as I've removed all traces of it from my menu.
2. The openSUSE menu appears to load just fine, but when selecting an option, it can't find the kernel file, kicking up tftp errors like `file /var/ftpd/openSUSE-12.1-i386//::openSUSE-12.1-i386linux not found`.  I don't know where it got that path from.

   - Using URL-style paths like `tftp://192.168.0.1/openSUSE-12.1-i386/` kicks up errors like `file /var/ftpd/openSUSE-12.1-i386//tftp:/192.168.0.1/openSUSE-12.1-i386linux not found`
   - Using paths like `192.168.0.1::openSUSE-12.1-i386/` kicks up errors like `file /var/ftpd/openSUSE-12.1-i386//192.168.0.1::openSUSE-12.1-i386linux not found`.  Are there other path formats I could try?
   - Using the APPEND command instead of appending the path to CONFIG command results in the same behaviour

I know I'm trying to mix pxelinux and isolinux, but it looks like it should work.  What am I doing wrong?